# child_process.exec not finding cmd in path

Tags: node.js, cmd, ffmpeg, path, child-process

So I have installed ffmpeg and added it into my path.
If I run `ffmpeg` in cmd.exe, it runs ffmpeg.exe.

But when I use this:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

await asyncExec(`ffmpeg -i ${filename}%05d.png ${aviname}`);
//Note: the variables are filled in
```

I receive this error:

```
Command failed: ffmpeg -i thing%05d.png thing.avi
'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.
```

I do not understand why this happpens. I'm just running this app in VSCode debugging.

Edit: asyncExec is this function:

```
const asyncExec = text => new Promise((res, rej) => {
    exec(text, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            rej(err);
        } else {
            res(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should try placing the output in the callback to really see what is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After restarting Visual Studio Code it works again. Weird.

Comment: Look, I was testing your code and the only thing you needed was to indicate the callback with the stdout, once I did this I ran normally.

Obviously I had to try another executable since I do not have ffmpeg installed in the system.

Comment: @Tvde1 This is why tech support recommendation #1 is 'power-cycle it'